# Why is JS function "toLocaleString" substracting hours?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-conversion

I am currently coding a web app in React that fetches data from an API. I am trying to display the timestamp data in a user-friendly format by converting it to a new date using the toLocaleString function.

I notice that there is a two-hour difference between the timestamp and the displayed time. Sometimes, there is only a one-hour difference.

but look what happens when I `console.log` this:

```
console.log(new Date(tData).toLocaleString("fr-FR") + " --- " + tData)
```

```
26/04/2023 14:22:22 --- 2023-04-26T12:22:22.985+00:00
```

Comment: The time in France is currently CEST, +02:00. So 12.22 in UTC, +00:00, _is_ 14:22 in France.

Comment: I assume it's because France lies in the time zone UTC+2 during summer time

Comment: We need a canonical "Because of timezones" Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Because of time zones, (+00:00) at the end means that it is in the UTC timezone.

Comment: UTC isn't a timezone, it's a time standard. ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).